# Typescript Neither, Either, but Not Both Properties

Tags: typescript

I'd like to assert that a type can have neither, either, but not both of a pair of properties.

The following does not work, although I'd have assumed it would. Apparently having `a: never` and `b: never` means that I have to provide both?

I also tried using `{}` in place of NeitherANorB which compiled and ran, but did not catch the fourth case where I incorrectly passed both options.

```
interface JustA {
    a: string;
    b: never;
}

interface JustB {
    a: never;
    b: string;
}

interface NeitherANorB {
    a: never;
    b: never;
}

type NotBothAAndB = JustA | JustB | NeitherANorB;

function testMe(x: NotBothAAndB) {
    console.log(x);
}

testMe({}); // OK
testMe({ a: "HI!" }); // OK
testMe({ b: "SUP?" }); // OK
testMe({ a: "HI!", b: "SUP?" }); // NOT OK
```

Comment: Change your `never` properties from required to optional (you can't have a required `never` property) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPPgW)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `{property?: never}` or `{property?: undefined}` to say that a property should not be present. Note that even in the former case, the property is allowed to be present so long as it has the value `undefined`, since that is just how Typescript handles optional properties. So this should do what you want:

```
type NotBoth =
    | {a: string, b?: never}
    | {a?: never, b: string}
    | {a?: never, b?: never}

// ok
const test1: NotBoth = {a: 'foo'};
const test2: NotBoth = {b: 'bar'};
const test3: NotBoth = {};
// error: 'string' is not assignable to 'undefined'
const testFail: NotBoth = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAQggFlAvAKCjqAfKAbwEMAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaKAIwH5z6IA3CagF9suAiS5Qe-aqzbkqdJsNz4ixCVIGyNfAcMwB6A1DgBrTAGM49KlGAQqARnLwkqDGvIByAGZw4XoIA3JbWtvZUAEwuCMjAaOhEclBebMTUgSFWNsB2DsAAzDFu8R6EwYbGAtRw1N4KDIxeULQUkghQxBQUtIz0xGwANtDAcCkArvQAJhA+DBBTXqE5eVQAYsS0g8VxCZ4pfgGy3mkZFUA)

For convenience, here's a helper type for constructing unions like this, where at most one of some properties is allowed:

```
// Simplify<T> just makes the resulting types more readable
type Simplify<T> = T extends infer S ? {[K in keyof S]: S[K]} : never
type NoneOf<T> = Simplify<{[K in keyof T]?: never}>
type AtMostOneOf<T> =
    | NoneOf<T>
    | {[K in keyof T]: Simplify<Pick<T, K> & NoneOf<Omit<T, K>>>}[keyof T]

type NotBoth = AtMostOneOf<{a: string, b: string}>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUEsFsAcBtIDMCeAeAKgPlAKwK4DOALqNAIYDWApoaMQBbWgBOt+8xkAdgOb0pYtMgHs2rauQAm5AEbxqAKGKDmUOIlSYcAXlAZQ1AB7Fq3KXR5JqLCKAD8oAN4BtANKgeoGihFIIALoAXBDuAQC+oCHc1ABuNsqqoAByIjEA8kjaoHrqCMjorh5ePn76AfbRcTbhWIlCoACCxACyIiTpGVnYOYqg-aAAPilp1JnafQPDRZ7c3tS+-hjBEDD5WgAKkADGlJgANKBuOABkI11o6dCQxAdHWA-hLqVLAYr1zKnEAEIijDlNVrtYidMZZJzkEIkFg8XiHWRQ4gwvi1d4gUAiSiKbZpEj0WjEACMIS+v3+eghIQA5EgRCIqeEANzY3GkUwkABMJL+ZIYAKcCNAVNk5BYDOZOO4ePZxAAzNyfn8+RSmYp0TYWGJqdDYVTPHRuH9QORCIRILxuHIFPQREL8OZqEgeNQpFSWVK2QSAGLkSDwBW8-mQoW0+nw6kisWqoA)

Comment: I guess [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) will make `prop?: never` and `prop?: undefined` act differently.

Comment: @jcalz Good to know.